# Change CSS class content from javascript [Firefox/XUL]

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, stylesheet, xul

I'm working on a firefox addon, and relies heavily on some dynamic changes with javascript. There are some UI elements (hbox/descriptions), which are styled using CSS classes. Now I wish to change the  a CSS class defintion from javascript, without having to work element id's. Is it possible ?

Similar questions had been asked before, but most of them are using php to generate a CSS or jquery based changes. 
Here's an example for my scenario: 
My XUL :

```
<box id="firefox-addon-box">
  <description id="description-1" class="description-text"> Some description </description>
  <description id="description-2" class="description-text"> Some description </description>
</box>
```

My CSS :

```
.description-text {
  font-size: 15px; 
  color: #fff; 
}
```

So I wish to change the font-size in `description-text` class to say, 20px dynamically. 
Now I know that we can [change the style using individual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/JavaScript#Action%3a_A_JavaScript_demonstration) id's, with a `getElementById()` and changing the style. But here I wish to change a class (which matters to a lot of elements), rather than to work on individual ids.
I also know that [we can point to another class definition](http://books.mozdev.org/html/mozilla-chp-5-sect-3.html#mozilla-CHP-5-SECT-3.3) by `setAttribute()` and change 'class' - this would again require working on individual id's. In reality, I have plenty of UI elements (all pointing to one CSS class), and many values changed in a CSS class. So my question is, is there a way to directly change a CSS class definition from javascript, without having to work on element ids ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37497445/1026): document.styleSheets is the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myVar = document.getElementsByClassName("description-text");
```

[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Thanks! So you're suggesting that I should get all the elements applying that specific class and do a mass-styling ? Okay, I think I can live with that. :) Actually, I was looking for a simpler solution, like directly changing the class content from javascript. Not sure if that is really possible.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a very similar question last night and figured it out this afternoon, which I have just tested as working on Firefox 29.0b1-49.0a1, may work on earlier versions, not sure about newer versions once XUL is removed (SDK or WebExtensions), but as it is pure JS/DOM/CSS, I think it might work ok.

What I learned was that it is easier than I thought.  Essentially, you find the specific style sheet, the specific rule, and edit the "style" of that rule using DOM, just like in HTML.

```
document.styleSheets[ i ].href
document.styleSheets[ i ].cssRules[ j ].selectorText
document.styleSheets[ i ].cssRules[ j ].style.fontSize
```

It all starts with the `document.styleSheets` array-like object, where `i` is the outer `document.styleSheet` loop index and `j` is the `cssRules` inner loop index.

The `href` is optional to consider, and is the URI of the style sheet.  If known, and if the sheet is not dynamically generated, and if you are certain that the selector you want exists only in that one file, then you can use it to limit searching through all selectors in all the ~10 style sheets that Firefox loads by default, before your add-on's first sheet is ever loaded.

Otherwise, you loop through all `document.styleSheets`, (optionally skip if `href` doesn't match), then loop through all the `cssRules` on each style sheet, and see if the `.selectorText` matches your desired selector, in the case of the OP: `.description-text` (note that you need the leading `.` or `#` etc, exactly as it appears in the CSS file, for classes or IDs, etc).

When you find the selector you want, then you can modify the `.style` object (well documented at [W3Schools DOM Style Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp)).  In the OP example, we want to change the `font-size` style to 20px, which would be `.style.fontSize = '20px'`.

Using these fundamentals, a more generic function can be crafted, to more easily reuse.  Perhaps a `getCSSrule` function which takes a required `selector` and an optional `href` argument, which will help you by getting the sheet and rule you want.  Perhaps a `getCSSsheet` function if you want to use just the `href` to get a sheet.  Perhaps a `setStyle` function to set the `style` and `value`.  Perhaps a set of `delCSSsheet` and `delCSSrule` functions if you want to discard these rather than modify.  And also an `insCSSsheet` and `insertCSSrule` function, maybe a `createCSSsheet` and `createCSSrule` as well.

This url ([Totally Pwn CSS with Javascript](https://web.archive.org/web/20130709232042/http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript)), despite the name, and defunct Web Archive only status, and being 9 years old or more, is actually still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same few months ago. I solved it with jQuery with `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` and more http://api.jquery.com/category/css/

Or if you want only Javascript use the HTML DOM from pure Javascript. Official documentation about that with examples: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: It's a small addon, and I don't plan to use jquery just to make a styling change.

Comment: Ok. So you can use the HTML DOM from pure Javascript. Official docuemntation about that with examples: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: @skozz w3schools is NOT **official** documentation

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you could use the `css` property :

```
$(".description-text").css({backgroundColor: "#ffe", borderLeft: "5px solid #ccc" });
```

All your elements that use the `description-text` class will be affected

[Documentation of jquery css property](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

**EDIT**

Or with pure javascript

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('description-text');

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ffe";
    elements[i].style.borderLeft = "5px solid #ccc";
    //any style you want to apply
}
```

[Documentation of javascript style](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp)

Comment: It's a small addon, and I don't plan to use jquery just to make a styling change.

Comment: I have edited my post with some pure javascript solution

Comment: Yes, getElementsByClassName() was already suggested by AlienArrays. It must be much easier with Jquery, but unfortunately, jquery would be too much for a small addon. Was wondering if there were some easier solutions. 
Any ways, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I will refrain from advising in favour of this method, but it is possible to also directly add css rules (or more complex remove them) doing the following

```
var css = '.description-text { font-size: 100px; }',
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);
```

There are *rare* occasions where this is a possible way to go and many situations where this is not the proper thing to do. You should never do this if you plan on overwriting the same thing multiple times (except if you remove the old rule first) and should only do this if you will use some other feature of CSS which builds upon this (e.g. new elements getting properly styles, 3rd party content getting properly styled, css animations, etc.).

Comment: Yes, there are [direct ways to load and register](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIStyleSheetService#loadAndRegisterSheet%28%29) a style sheet with XPCOM (ff addon). But adding/overwriting sheets will make it more complex. 
Thanks for your time though!

Comment: I do not understand, there is no `<head>` tag in XUL.  Then how exactly do you get at the `<?xml-stylesheet href="..."?>` elements that come before the `<!DOCTYPE ...>` tag?  Or is that an "implicit" head?